# can google maps on mobile phones can have plugins?

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation

i want to use data from google maps, especialy the navigation functionality. Is this possible by plugin or wrapping the application?

I want to develop my own navigation service and use GoogleMaps for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of samples available all over the internet which build on top of mapview. Its not a plugin architecture but based on containment model. I think you can easily achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can embed the `MapView` widget into your application for displaying a map. You cannot use this for some navigation services per the terms of service.

There are no plugins for the standard Google Maps application for Android.